# TDD Scenario: Looking for advice

Tags: tdd

I'm currently in an environment where we are parsing data off of the client's website. I want to use my tests to ensure that when the client changes their site, I know when we are no longer receiving the information.

My first approach was to do pure integration tests where my tests hit the client's site and assert that the data was found. However half way through and 500 tests in, the test run has become unbearable and in some cases started timing out. So I cleared out as many tests that I could without loosing the core protection they are providing and I'm down to 350 or so. I'm left with a fear to add more tests to only break all the tests. I also find myself not running the 5+ minute duration (some clients will be longer as this is based on speed of communication with their site) when I make changes anymore. I consider this a complete failure.

I've been putting a lot of thought into this and asking around the office, my thoughts for my next attempt at this is to pull down the client's pages and write tests against these embedded resources in my projects. This will give me my higher test coverage and allow me to go back to testing in isolation. However I would need to be notified when they make changes and then re-pull down the pages to test against. I don't think the clients will adhere to this.

A suggestion was made to me to augment this with a suite of 'random' integration tests that serve the same function as my failed tests (hit the clients site) but in a lot less number than before. I really don't like the idea of random testing, where the possibility of sometimes getting red lights and some times getting green lights with the same code. But this so far sounds like the best idea I've heard to still gain the awareness of when the client's site has changed and my code no longer finds the data.

Has anyone found themselves testing an environment like this? Any suggestions from the testing community for me?

Comment: Do you mean you're scraping data off an external web-site? If yes, can you have them give you a heads-up before a major change? If not, tag a minimal subset of your tests (a smoke) and run them first. Once this basic set passes, then invoke the rest of the suite.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions. Definitely good information to mull over.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the big test has become unbearable, it suggests that you are running this test suite manually.  You shouldn't have to.  It should just be running constantly in the background, at whatever speed it takes to complete the suite - and then start over again (perhaps after a delay if there are associated costs).  Only when something goes wrong should you get an alert.

If there is something about your tests that causes them to get slower as their number grows - find it and fix it.  Tests should be independent of one another, so simply having more of them shouldn't cause individual tests to time out.

Comment: I would love more info on the constant running tests in the background. Currently I'm using resharper and alt r+u+n to fire off all my tests after I make changes. I'm pushing to get our environment to CI where we have our tests automated on commit/push. This environment isn't quite there yet.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to try to isolate as much as possible the part of code that deals with the uncertainty. This part should be an API that works as a service used by all the other code. This way you would be protecting most of your code against changes.

The stable parts of the code should be unit-tested. With that part being independent from the connection to client's site running the tests should be way quicker and it would also make those tests more reliable.

The part that has to deal with the changes on the client's websites can be reduced. This way you are not solving the problem but at least you're minimising it and centralising it in only one module of your code.

Suggesting to the clients to expose the data as a web service would be the best for you. But I guess that doesn't depend on you :P.

Comment: Yah, we have restrictions on how we are allowed to communicate with the client, you hit the nail on the head there. I agree with isolating it as much as possible, I pulled all of the parsing logic into their own classes and only ever do it there. Then I'm passing in everything it needs (really just the html) to my parsers. I'll put more thought into removing it even further, It being the worst part of the problem, would be great in a higher level of extraction.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at dividing your tests up, maybe into separate assemblies that can be run independently.  I typically have a unit tests assembly and a slower running integration tests assembly.

My unit tests assembly is very fast (because the code is tested in isolation using mocks) and gets run very frequently as I develop.  The integration tests are slower and I only run them when I finish a feature / check in or if I have a bad feeling about breaking something.

Maybe you could do something similar or even take the idea further and have 3 test suites with the third containing even slower client UI polling tests.

If you don't have a continuous integration server / process you should look at setting one up.  This would continuously build you software and execute the tests.  This could be set up to monitor check-ins and work in the background, sending out a notification if anything fails.  With this in place you wouldn't care how long your client UI polling tests take because you wouldn't ever have to run them yourself.

Comment: I'm definitely going to take the approach of dividing my integration and isolation tests up this time around, I don't want to loose all of my tests because 1/2 of them are time sinks. I'm also working on getting my environment into CI, just not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely split the tests out - separate unit tests from integration tests as a minimum.

As Martyn said, get a Continuous Integration system in place. I use Teamcity, which is excellent, easy to use, free for the first 20 builds, and you can happily run it on your own machine if you don't have a server at your disposal - http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/

Set up one build to run on every check in, and make that build run your unit tests, or fast-running tests if you will.

Set up a second build to run at midnight every night (or some other convenient time), and include in this the longer running client-calling integration tests. With this in place, it won't matter how long the tests take, and you'll get a big red flag first thing in the morning if your client has broken your stuff. You can also run these manually on demand, if you suspect there might be a problem.